# How to let user download a pdf file right after he visits a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

Simple question, I've got a pdf generated on page load, subsequently I want to let the user download the file.

Is there a way to do it? To show the download dialog after pdf was created?

I've tried this:

```
<%response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+filename+"\"");%>
```

But where do I define, which file do I want user to download? Because code above leads to user downloading some corrupted empty pdf file.

Comment: must be possible... can you show the code of your page and pdf generation?

Comment: I know it is possible, but how should I do it? Code generating the pdf is not necessary here, since it is created successfully. Now I just need to let users download it.

Comment: You need to send the pdf contents to the browser after setting this header. I think it will be easier for you to have a hidden iframe inside your page which points to a script that outputs this header and the pdf contents. Otherwise the user will see a blank page after/while downloading the file.

Comment: It doesn't matter what page does the user see, I just want him to download non corrupted file :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do this with a Servlet instead of a JSP. You have more control over the code and it is less fragile (if you handle the response content in the JSP and you have even a single space or line feed between your scriptlets, that can be written to the output stream 
corrupting the file content).

So have a look at this [FileServlet example](http://balusc.blogspot.ro/2007/07/fileservlet.html) and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: You can do it with a JSP too, but it's ugly.